# Wordpress page to populate WP database

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a custom page on my WP instance which I want to interact with my database instance, ideally the standard table WP uses for posts.

This page pages retrieves an online stream from a set of social network channels, and I do want to persist this stream into the database so to form a sort of "archive".

So I have two questions:
a) Would it better creating a separate table, or is it more convenient adding everything in the wp-post table (or whatever it is called), classifying the item as social or something else
b) How can I interact with my WP database using WP Api so to not reinvent the wheel?

Thanks

Comment: for me, I would probably use default wp_posts table for this purpose. since it is a generic table plus you can define custom post types as well..you can read more about using and defining suctopm post types here..
http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Types

Comment: Check the WordPress codex, it has all the information you need.
https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb
https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_post
http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Types

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. After reading the wpdb reference, I still have a doubt. Before inserting a row in the db, should I still use the $$wpdb->prepare ... or the insert API does an implicit call?

Answer (score 0):

Normally, we should only [create our own tables](https://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_Tables_with_Plugins) if WordPress features and organisation are not enough to deal with our data.
Nowadays, [Custom Post Types](http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Types) (`wp_posts` db table) and [Custom Fields](http://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Fields) (`wp_postmeta` db table) are used in a variety of plugins (from Advanced Custom Fields to WooCommerce).

Then we use, among others, [`WP_Query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) to retrieve data and [`wp_update_post()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_update_post) and [`update_post_meta()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_post_meta) to insert data.

In any case, [data validation](https://codex.wordpress.org/Data_Validation) and [security checks](https://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Nonces) are always important.